# How can i print whole webpage and iFrame in same paper using primefaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, jqprint

working on a huge web portal using primefaces, the portal single page is consist of 2 parts

```
- PART I - the page layout
  - header
  - sidebar
  - footer
- PART II - the main content in iframe
```

when i'm using print this page using following code:

### button

```
<p:printer target="printable" />
```

### target print

```
<h:panelGroup id="printable">
    <div class="pageTitle">
        <h:outputText value="#{main.moduleName}" rendered="false" />
    </div>

    <div class="userData">
        <h:outputLabel id="prtalTimeStamp" value="#{main.timeStamp}"
           rendered="false" />

        <h:outputLabel value="#{main.userIdLabel}" rendered="false" />
    </div>

    <div class="iframeDiv" id="content">
        <iframe src="#{main.currentFunctionUrl}" width="100%" id="ifr"
                    frameborder="0" height="100%" onload="disableContextMenu();" onMyLoad="disableContextMenu();" scrollbar='no' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' hspace='0' align='middle'></iframe>
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

## The problem

1- the primeface printer (jqprint) cannot print layout page and iframe in same paper page , print in a separate pages.

2- if the page full of content, its only print one page.

---

please help, using primefaces or normal html/css/js

Comment: retagged, Primefaces has no own printing mechanism, it is only including jqprint, provide PrimeFaces version